# How to deserialize 422 unprocessable entity error model and bind the errors to asp.net core razor pages model state

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, modelstate, http-status-code-422

My `Asp.Net Core 3.1 API` returns `422 Unprocessable Entity` error response as shown below:

```
{
  "type": "https://test.com/modelvalidationproblem",
  "title": "One or more model validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 422,
  "detail": "See the errors property for details.",
  "instance": "/api/path",
  "traceId": "8000003f-0001-ec00-b63f-84710c7967bb",
  "errors": {
    "FirstName": [
      "The FirstName field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

How to deserialize this response and add the errors to model validation error in `Asp.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages`?

I tried to create model as shown below,

**Error Model:**

```cs
public class UnprocessableEntity
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
    public string TraceId { get; set; }
    public Errors Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Errors
{
    ....// what should I need to add here? Keys and messages will be dynamic
}
```

However what I should add inside `Errors` class? The error keys and messages will be dynamic.

Once above things is known, I can add model state errors in my razor pages as shown below,

```cs
using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var errorResponse = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<UnprocessableEntity>(responseStream);

foreach (var error in errorResponse.errors)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(error.key, error.Message[0]); // I'm stuck here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should ensure the key field names are the same as the json returned from api(`pay attention to case`).

```
 public class UnprocessableEntity
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string tTitle { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
    public string instance { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the fields of the `Errors` class should contain all the fields of the validated class, and the field names should be consistent, but you need to `define their type as an array to receive`, because each field returned by errors in json is an array. (here i created a simple validated class named `StudInfo`):

```
    public class StudInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public class Errors
    {
        public List<string> Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then the code you can use as follow:

```
       using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
       var errorResponse = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<UnprocessableEntity>(responseStream);
        var t = typeof(Errors);
        var fieldNames = typeof(Errors).GetProperties()
                        .Select(field => field.Name)
                        .ToList();
        foreach (var name in fieldNames)
        {
            List<string> errorLists = (List<string>)errorResponse.errors.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(errorResponse.errors);
            if (errorLists != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(name, errorLists[0]); 
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @Yongqing Yu answer and made it generic.

**422 Error Model:**

```cs
public class UnprocessableEntity<T>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("detail")]
    public string Detail { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("instance")]
    public string Instance { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("traceId")]
    public string TraceId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("errors")]
    public T Errors { get; set; }
}
```

**Model:**

```cs
public class EventRegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [RegularExpression(ValidationConstants.ALPHABETSWITHSPACE, ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [RegularExpression(ValidationConstants.ALPHABETSWITHSPACE, ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter 10 digit Mobile Number")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression(ValidationConstants.NUMBERSONLY, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile Number")]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**Error Model:**

```cs
public class EventRegistrationValidationErrors
{
    public IEnumerable<string> FirstName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

While deserialzing,

```cs
using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var errorResponse = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<UnprocessableEntity<EventRegistrationValidationErrors>>(responseStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
var errorFieldNames = typeof(EventRegistrationValidationErrors)
                        .GetProperties()
                        .Select(field => field.Name)
                        .ToList();

foreach (var errorField in errorFieldNames)
{
    var errorLists = (List<string>)errorResponse.errors
                        .GetType()
                        .GetProperty(errorField)
                        .GetValue(errorResponse.errors);

    if (!(errorLists is null))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError($"Event.{errorField}", errorLists[0]);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone out there.